# What to enter for NODE_ENDPOINT on blk.io explorer

Tags: nodes

blk-io/blk-explorer: https://github.com/blk-io/blk-explorer-free

Hi,

I'm relatively new to ethereum, and I am having difficulty implementing the blk.io block explorer (for my private ethereum network).

I was wondering what to enter for 'NODE_ENDPOINT' ? I have no idea what a node endpoint is

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a block explorer, first you need to run an Ethereum node, like [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)
and then connect your explorer to it - use the same address you tell `geth` to use with `--rpcaddr` flag. Or you can find a public node exposing all the API required by the explorer and connect there, but my advise is to run your own.